# Save/Load a file in android for a game

Tags: java, android, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I have created a game in Android. I have written a class for input/ouput with prefer install location external. I want to make some basic questions. First of all the file I use is a .txt (I know that its not the best way to save your data but I use it for testing). The strange part is that when the the game is over it should automatically save the user highscores but it does not, so when I close the app and restart it the highscores have disappeared. I would also like to learn what the prefered file type for saving settings/highscores/coins etc (hopefully secured) is. Lastly I debug the game using a Nexus 5 whitch does not have external storage (it should be stored locally though). This is my code, thanks in advance :).

```
public class AndroidFileIO implements FileIO {
    Context context;
    AssetManager assets;
    String externalStoragePath;

    public AndroidFileIO(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.assets = context.getAssets();
        this.externalStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath() + File.separator;
    }

    public InputStream readAsset(String fileName) throws IOException {
        return assets.open(fileName);
    }

    public InputStream readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        return new FileInputStream(externalStoragePath + fileName);
    }

    public OutputStream writeFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        return new FileOutputStream(externalStoragePath + fileName);
    }

    public SharedPreferences getPreferences() {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    }
}
```

my game class has this method

```
public FileIO getFileIO() {
    return fileIO;
}
```

this is the way i load the file

```
Settings.load(game.getFileIO());
```

and finaly my save/load methods of the settings class

```
public static void load(FileIO files) {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                files.readFile("mrnom.txt")));
        soundEnabled = Boolean.parseBoolean(in.readLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            highscores[i] = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // :( It's ok we have defaults
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // :/ It's ok, defaults save our day
    } finally {
        try {
            if (in != null)
                in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}

public static void save(FileIO files) {
    BufferedWriter out = null;
    try {
        out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                files.writeFile("mrnom.txt")));
        out.write(Boolean.toString(soundEnabled));
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            out.write(Integer.toString(highscores[i]));
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
    } finally {
        try {
            if (out != null)
                out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Here save is called

```
private void updateGameOver(List<TouchEvent> touchEvents) {
    int len = touchEvents.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        TouchEvent event = touchEvents.get(i);
        if(event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP) {
            if(event.x >= 128 && event.x <= 192 &&
               event.y >= 200 && event.y <= 264) {
                if(Settings.soundEnabled)
                    Assets.click.play(1);
                //debug begin
                FileIO fileIO = game.getFileIO();
                Settings.save(fileIO);
                //debug end
                game.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(game));
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where you actually call the save/load methods? Sounds like a lifecycle issue.

Comment: You could just use a shared preferences object

Comment: The ''main'' class is called AndroidGame. This class extends the activity class and it also overrides the onCreate() method etc. It also handles the renderer(other thread), input, event handling etc. Then i have another class that extends the AndroidGame. It uses new to create a new instance of all the assets i need and it also loads the file using this Settings.load(game.getFileIO());. I call the safe method after the gameOver screen. Give me a min to upload what you asked

Comment: @Submersed Correct if i am wrong, shared preferences are for activities that share files.Also Shared preferences do not work with serilized objects which is my finish type file.

Comment: i also tested the save method inside the onPause(). Still doesnt work

Comment: SharedPreferences is definitely the API to use to save these kinds of things.

Comment: SharedPreferences can be accessed anywhere you have a context.  Also, you're just saving ints and boolean, which are all supported types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in the `save` method when you write the strings to the `out` reference. You are not saving a value per line, but are later reading a value per line in your `load` method. With the current code you save the following in your *mrnom.txt* file: `true10203040` instead of `true\n10\n20\n30\n40`.

To fix this, one way is to change:

```
out.write(Boolean.toString(soundEnabled));
```

to

```
out.write(Boolean.toString(soundEnabled) + "\n");
```

**AND**

```
out.write(Integer.toString(highscores[i]));
```

to

```
out.write(Integer.toString(highscores[i]) + "\n");
```